# PrimeNG - PrimeFaces

Tags: angular, forms

I'm using Angular forms with PrimeNG and I'm trying to initialize a dropdown with an initial value but isn't work for me. Also I tried to use also setValue method but doesn't work.

This is the html code

```
<form [formGroup]="filtersForm">
    <div class="ui-g-3">
       <div class="form-control">
         <p-dropdown formControlName="dimensionRule" class="dropdown" [options]="monedasMock" optionLabel="label"></p-dropdown>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is the JavaScript code wrote in TypeScript

```
public ngOnInit() : void {

    this.monedasMock = [
        { 'label': 'Euro', 'value': '1' },
        { 'label': 'Peseta', 'value': '2' },
        { 'label': 'Florin', 'value': '3' },
        { 'label': 'Marco', 'value': '4' }
    ];

    this.filtersForm = this.fBuilder.group({
        "descriptionRule": new FormControl(),
        "dimensionRule": new FormControl('Florin'), // This is the value that I want to initialize
        "processRule": new FormControl()
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you have any console error/unexpected behavior?

Comment: Nop I don't have any errors in the console.log. The console log is empty

Comment: I'd have a view questions, like are you importing the SelectItem api into the component, are you actually implementing ngoninit from angular core instead of just naming a method the same and hoping you're in the lifecycle, and if you read [the documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown) to kind of follow the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a [SelectItem](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/common/selectitem.ts) {value:any, label:string}.

to preselect an option in dropdown element you must pass "value" property.

In this case:

```
...
"dimensionRule": new FormControl('3'),
...
```

and "optionLabel" is not required with SelectItem collection.